# how to find sum of even no till 100 in linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sum

what should be condition for while before adding while loops it prints even no upto 100 but I need to print sum of even numbers

```
#!/bin/bash
 sum=0
   for((n=2;n<=100;n=n+2))
   do
      echo $n
      while [[$n  0]]   # what should be condition for while loop
      do
         sum= `expr sum + $n`
      done
    echo "sum is $sum "
   done
```

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop.

Comment: You also don't need `expr`.

Comment: Why are you doing this in `bash`?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 3):

Does this count ^_* :

```
kent$ seq -s + 2 2 100|bc
2550
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the `while` loop at all. You're already iterating with the `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for((n=2;n<=100;n=n+2))
do
    echo $n
    ((sum+=n))
done
echo "sum is $sum "
```

Comment: `sum=$((sum + n))` or `(( sum += n ))` (or `: $((sum += n))`, I guess). No need for `let`, which is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, didin't know about the obsolescence.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=0;
 for i in {1..100}; do 
    if [[ $(( i % 2 )) == 0 ]]; then
       let k=k+i
           fi ; done
echo $k
```

Prints

2550

or this:

```
k=0; for i in {1..100}; do 
    if (( i % 2 == 0 )); then 
         (( k=k+i ))  ; fi ; done ; echo $k
```